# Use regex to match only sequential (but not necessarily consecutive) matches

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm trying to match a regex with a string as long as possible. This is the string to look in:

```
"xxaxxbxxbxbxxbxxbxxbxxdxx"
```

The pattern to match is:

```
"bcda"
```

The pattern is to be interpreted as follows:

- `b`: There are several of them in the string. The first one should match.
- `c`: There isn't one in the string, so nothing is returned.
- `d`: There is just one near the end of the string. It should be returned.
- `a`: There is one at the beginning of the string. Since `b`, `c`, and `d` were sought first and results are returned, `a` will not be returned.

The expected return is:

```
"bd"
```

It may be that regex match is not the correct way to accomplish this, but I'd like to ask for assistance with one. The basic question is this: can I use regex to generically find a substring that represents as much of a an ordered, but not necessarily consecutive, sequence of candidate characters as it possibly can? If so, how?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Here's an example of a regex you can use: http://rubular.com/r/tMw2SA0Rtt

Comment: OK it looks like you changed your question.. regex is no longer the way to go here. Your requirements are a bit arbitrary; there's no explanation as to why we find 'd' but give up on 'a'. I guess because we encountered a failure ('c')? Anyway, you would not be able to simply plug a generalized pattern into any regular expression now without some actual programming.

Comment: Have you tried something? Show your attempt.

Comment: I've summarized the question at the end as best I can.

Comment: You would find 'd' because it comes before a in the order of 'bcda'. The only circumstance where a would be found is if none of b or c or d could be found before it. So in xyxyxyxyax, a would be found since b and c and d were all tried first, but weren't found.

Answer (score 1):

As @sawa explained, you cannot do this with a single regex. Here is a recursive solution.

```
def consecutive_matches(str, pattern)
  return '' if str.empty? || pattern.empty?
  ch, pat = pattern[0], pattern[1..-1]
  i = str.index(ch)
  if i
    ch + consecutive_matches(str[i+1..-1], pat)
  else             
    consecutive_matches(str, pat)
  end
end

str = "xxaxxbxxbxbxxbxxbxxbxxdxx"

consecutive_matches(str, "bcda") #=> "bd"
consecutive_matches(str, "abcd") #=> "abd"
consecutive_matches(str, "dabc") #=> "d"
consecutive_matches(str, "cfgh") #=> ""
```

Comment: Not sure if the name of the method is appropriate. Shouldn't it rather be `non_consecutive_matches`?

Comment: Correct. Sequential_but_maybe_not_consecutive_matches might fit the bill.

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to do that with a single regex match. A capture in a regex must be a substring of the original string. `bd` here is not, so there is no way to match that as a single capture.

Comment: So, for clarity, you mean to say that xbxdx does not contain the substring "bd" because b and d are non-consecutive?

Comment: No, `"bd"` is **not** a substring of `"xbxdx"`.

Comment: Then, is bd a substring of  "xxb dxx" ?